# Pass a filter age in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, filter, sms

That's my view page with a 2 filters, one for age and one for type of job

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwuC.jpg)

im stuck because they asking me to change db for give the possibility to not have birthday inside my table and this part is ok,
but now i would like that if there is not birthday date inside the db , the only filter that must work is the occupation,

if i set for example 18-65 age years old and job it
i would like to send sms also for ppl that dont have the birthday but they are in it

thats my code i hope someone has an idea

Bulk_messages.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <style>
        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input[type="tel"],
        textarea {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        input[type="tel"]:focus,
        textarea:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
            outline: none;
        }

        .intl-tel-input {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .intl-tel-input .flag-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            left: 10px;
        }

        .intl-tel-input .country-list {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 9999;
            top: 60px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 10px;
            max-height: 200px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .panel-heading1{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .intl-tel-input .country-list .country {
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .intl-tel-input .country-list .country.active {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Mehrere Meldungen</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('bulk_send.sms') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('age_range') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="age_range" class="col-md-4 control-label">Alter</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="age_range" name="age_range" class="form-control"/>
                @if ($errors->has('age_range'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('age_range') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('occupation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="occupation" class="col-md-4 control-label">Beruf</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select id="occupation" name="occupation" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value="">Auswählen Job</option>
                  @foreach($occupations as $occupation)
                  <option value="{{ $occupation['occupation'] }}">{{ $occupation['occupation'] }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('occupations'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('occupation') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('message') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="message" class="col-md-4 control-label">Nachricht</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" required>{{ old('message') }}</textarea>
                @if ($errors->has('message'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('message') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Nachricht senden
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#age_range").ionRangeSlider({
      type: "double",
      grid: true,
      min: 15,
      max: 100,
      from: 25,
      to: 65,
      prefix: "Alter ",
      postfix: "Jahren",
      step: 1,
      prettify_enabled: true,
      prettify_separator: ","
    });
  });
</script>


@endsection
```

that my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('contacts.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'firstName' => 'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'occupation' => 'required',
            'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'country_code' => 'required',
            'country_iso_code' => 'required'
        ]);

        Contact::create($validatedData);
        return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('success', 'Contact created successfully!');
    }

    public function edit(Contact $contact)
    {
        return view('contacts.edit', compact('contact'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'firstName' => 'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'occupation' => 'required',
            'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'country_code' => 'required',
            'country_iso_code' => 'required'
        ]);

        $contact->update($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('success', 'Contact updated successfully!');
    }

    public function destroy(Contact $contact)
    {
        $contact->delete();

        return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('success', 'Contact deleted successfully!');
    }

    public function bulk_contacts_filters(Request $request){
        $occupations = Contact::select('occupation')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get()->toArray();
            
        return view('bulk_messages', compact('occupations'));
    }
}
```

and this is my SmsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contact;
use App\SmsHistory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SMSGate\Client;
use SMSGate\SMSRequest;

class SmsController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request){
        $contact = null;
        if($request->has('contact_id')) {
            $contact = Contact::find($request->contact_id);
        }
        return view('home', compact('contact'));
    }
    
    public function send_sms(Request $request){
        $this->sms_gate_request($request->country_code.$request->phone, $request->message, !empty($request->contact_id ? $request->contact_id : null));
        return back();
    }

    public function send_sms_bulk(Request $request){
        $query = Contact::query();

        if ($request->has('age_range')) {
            $age = explode(';',$request->age_range);
            $startDate = now()->subYears($age[0]);
            $endDate = now()->subYears($age[1])->subDay();
            $query->whereBetween('birthday', [$endDate, $startDate]);
        }

        if (!empty($occupation)) {
            $query->where('occupation', $occupation);
        }

        $contacts = $query->get();

        foreach($contacts as $contact) {
            $this->sms_gate_request($contact->country_code.$contact->phone_number, $request->message, $contact->id);
        }
        
    }


    public function sms_gate_request($number, $msg, $contact_id){
        $gate = new Client(env('SMS_GATE_SUBMIT_URL'));
        $sms = new SMSRequest;
        $sms->setType(Client::TYPE_TEXT)
            ->setAuthUsername(env('SMS_GATE_USERNAME'))
            ->setAuthPassword(env('SMS_GATE_PASSWORD'))
            ->setSender(env('SMS_GATE_SENDER'))
            ->setReceiver($number)
            ->setText($msg)
            ////make sure to set the real URL for your webhook handler
            // ->setDlrUrl('http://localhost:8000/dlr.php')
            ->setDlrMask(Client::DLR_MASK_STANDARD);
        try {
            $gate->send($sms);
            SmsHistory::create([
                'phone_number' => $number,
                'message' => $msg,
                'contact_id' => $contact_id
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            echo "Error sending SMS with code: " . $exc->getCode() . " and message: " . $exc->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

i lost my mind about this thing

Comment: Check if the age_range field is empty or not in your controller action where you process the form submission. If it's empty, set the from and to variables to 0 and 200 (or any value that is outside the range of age) respectively. Otherwise, use the values submitted by the user.

Comment: you mean in the function send_sms_bulk right?

Comment: yes, check if the age_range is empty or not and then perform your required actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your contacts by using this code in your `send_sms_bulk` method:

```php
$contacts = $query->whereBetween('birthday', [$startDate, $endDate]) // Filter contacts with age between your filter range
            ->orWhereNull('birthday') // Also filter contacts with null age
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thx pooria,  it works

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the solution works! If you found it helpful, please consider voting for it to help others who may encounter the same problem. Your vote would be greatly appreciated. tnx again

Comment: unfortunatly i cant vote because i dont have the reputation yet